# BeautifulSoup not able to read element

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap data from https://www.yelp.com.
Below is links from yelp.com

```
https://www.yelp.com/adredir?ad_business_id=9loHqjf1yIWv27Jowkymhg&campaign_id=-Fo9UnT0LE3bWCph6c32fA&click_origin=search_results&placement=above_search&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2Fbiz%2Fdennys-orlando-4&request_id=709bf3cd865829d4&signature=7e7c9168ba838dca1e40b0f48e8e91b2b3e05123488ee1e2da3732ee8fbd1ca9&slot=0
```

above mentioned link redirects to

https://www.yelp.com/biz/dennys-orlando-4

Due to which my code is failing i guess.

```
` my_web_page = requests.get(value["shop_full_url"])
  my_soup = BeautifulSoup(my_web_page.text, 'html.parser')
  comment_pages_list = my_soup.findAll(class_="page-of-pages")
  for comment_pages in comment_pages_list:
        print(comment_pages.text.strip().replace("Page 1 of ", "")
```

Comment: can you add from where you got this link ?

Comment: sorry use this link above link in question is giving 404 error

Comment: https://www.yelp.com/adredir?ad_business_id=9loHqjf1yIWv27Jowkymhg&campaign_id=-Fo9UnT0LE3bWCph6c32fA&click_origin=search_results&placement=above_search&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2Fbiz%2Fdennys-orlando-4&request_id=709bf3cd865829d4&signature=7e7c9168ba838dca1e40b0f48e8e91b2b3e05123488ee1e2da3732ee8fbd1ca9&slot=0

Comment: i mean where did you found it in first place

Comment: I scaped it from some other page from yelp.com only